# Passing variable value in structure object

Tags: arduino-mega, eeprom

in this code i want to pass value of variable char array 'pass' in object "MyObject". But i am getting this error.

```
    Arduino: 1.6.11 (Windows 8.1), Board: "Arduino/Genuino Mega or Mega 2560, ATmega2560 (Mega 2560)"

C:\Users\XXX\Desktop\EEPROM_put\EEPROM_put.ino: In function 'void setup()':

EEPROM_put:17: error: array must be initialized with a brace-enclosed initializer

};

^

exit status 1
array must be initialized with a brace-enclosed initializer

This report would have more information with
"Show verbose output during compilation"
option enabled in File -> Preferences.
```

when i change pass to *pass, result of EEPROM.get() is 1 and 6, instead of 1, 62345, 7539514682.

```
#include <EEPROM.h>
struct MyObject {
boolean stat;
char password[6];
char mobile[11];
}; 

char pass[6]="62345";
void setup() {
Serial.begin(9600);
while (!Serial);
MyObject customVar = {
  1,
  pass,
  "7539514682"
 };
EEPROM.put(1, customVar);
Serial.print("Written custom data type!");
}

void loop() {

}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use `class` and `constructor`

```
#include <EEPROM.h>
class MyObject {
    boolean stat;
    char password[6];
    char mobile[11];
  public:
    MyObject(bool tempStat, char tempPassword[], char tempMobile[])
    {
      stat = tempStat;
      strcpy(password, tempPassword);//As suggested by mikael
      strcpy(mobile, tempMobile);
    }
};

char pass[6] = "62345";
void setup() {
  Serial.begin(9600);
  while (!Serial);
  MyObject customVar(true, pass, "7539514682");
  EEPROM.put(1, customVar);
  Serial.print("Written custom data type!");
}
```

Comment: getting output like this:


Read custom object from EEPROM: 
1
62345 7539514682T
7539514682T

Comment: What is the expected Output

Comment: Should copy with the sizeof(password) and not break on zero? strcpy() might be easier.

Comment: Sorry forgot NULL terminating character. Made changes

Comment: @Sniper still not getting correct output, now getting some random characters, output is :
1
62ÿ! 75
75
Expected output is 1, 62345, 7539514682

Comment: Did strcpy worked?

Answer (score 0):

While the method from Sniper's answer works, it involves copying the
data, which is something you often want to avoid on an Arduino. The
simplest fix to your problem is probably to initialize your `password`
field with a literal string, just like you did with the `mobile` field:

```c++
MyObject customVar = {
    1,
    "62345",
    "7539514682"
};
```

or maybe, if you want the password to be written near the top of the
program,

```c++
#define PASS "62345"

MyObject customVar = {
    1,
    PASS,
    "7539514682"
};
```

Another option is to not store the strings in the object. Instead, store
them elsewhere and have the object only hold *pointers* to them:

```c++
struct MyObject {
    boolean stat;
    const char *password;
    const char *mobile;
};

char pass[6] = "62345";

[...]

MyObject customVar = {
    1,
    pass,
    "7539514682"
};
```

Note that, in this case, the mobile number is stored by the compiler as
an unnamed string constant. Because it is constant, the `mobile` field
has been typed as `const char *`. I typed the `password` field
identically for symmetry, but in this use case it need not be `const`.